# Как обновить значение DataGrid TextColumn при изменении значения другого текстового столбца (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

Использую Entity Framework 6, database first. Есть автоматически сгенерированные сущности, вроде такой:

```
public partial class PutlZeroMileage
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FK_ZM { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> KmFact { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> FctBeginTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> FctEndTime { get; set; }
    public string ControlPointB { get; set; }
    public string ControlPointE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Consider { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> FK_Putl { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Time { get; set; }

    public virtual Putl Putl { get; set; }
    public virtual ZeroMileage ZeroMileage { get; set; }
}
```

К свойствам привязаны колонки в Datagrid. Нужно чтобы при изменении одного из свойств(например FctBeginTime) менять Time. По идее в set свойства FctBeginTime можно пересчитывать Time, и вызывать PropertyChanged. Но это сгенерированный код, перегенерация всё сотрет. Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У вас класс помечен как partial, сделайте еще одну часть в которой объявите свойства уведомляющие о своем изменении, и получающие/записывающие данные вот в эти сгенерированные свойства. В таблицу через Binding привязывайте ваши свойства с уведомлением о изменении.

   public partial class PutlZeroMileage : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {

   ```
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   public Nullable<decimal> BeginTime
   {
       get
       {
           return FctBeginTime;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value != FctBeginTime)
           {
               FctBeginTime = value;
               CalcTime();
               OnPropertyChanged();
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Time))
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. Сделайте класс обертку, в которой этот будет поле с экземпляром вашего класса из БД, а в публичной части будут только те свойства которые вым нужны в пользовательском интерфейсе, их уже делаете правильными, а данные они хранят в классе модели.